Biasing circuit for MAR-8SM+ Amplifier
I'm struggling with the given circuit for the Mini-Circuits MAR-8SM+.  The biasing circuit consists of Rbias(RES=260ohm), Cbias(HVC-0402,GRM43), and an RF Choke(TDK). 
The Minimum voltage requirement of the given amplifier is 3.6V and the absolute current requirement is 65mA. 
The given diagram is the simulation result of MAR-8SM+. I have assumed the RF Choke (L2)value to be 560nH as the datasheet is lacking the information. from the datasheet , the biasing voltage is 12V for 260ohm biasing Resistance.
how can i achieve the required current and voltage at the biasing input. pls help!!!!!

Normal operating voltage/current is 7.8V/36mA. The datasheet suggests using 115 Ohm for a 12V supply. 120 Ohm would be fine too. The value of the choke depends on the lower frequency corner which you have not divulged.

In future please inline links as I have done in the edit. Put the text you want the link to say, select the text, click the link button at the top of the editor, and past the link.  I've also stripped off the text (I believe it's some tracking info) after .pdf in the URL, some sites add that stuff on but it can be stripped off and the link still works.

Also you shouldn't post photos of your screen,, they are difficult to read. Instead use a properly cropped screenshot.


The Minimum voltage requirement of the given amplifier is 3.6V and the absolute current requirement is 65mA.

From the datasheet, the ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM current permitted is 65 mA, with the recommended typical operating current being 36 mA. You should aim to bias it at the recommended current.
Nowhere in the datahseet is 3.6 V mentioned.

from the datasheet , the biasing voltage is 12V for 260ohm biasing Resistance.

No. From the datasheet, the recommended Rbias is 115 Ω at 12 V input. This is consistent with the typical operating voltage of 7.8 V, which gives 4.2 V across Rbias, for 36.5 mA calculated current.
